# JanusGraph gremlin crashes when adding many history properties

Tags: kotlin, gremlin, janusgraph

I am adding a vertex with a very large number of properties (17 properties and 1500 history entries in each). At first, there was a recursion error at startup. I fixed it, took out the next() method separately. Now he writes another error. Sometimes, it turns out to load from the second or third time on top of the previous times with an error. How can I fix it?

```
fun createNodeHistory(
        listOntologyTags: List<String>,
        propertiesHistory: List<PropertyHistory>,
        mandatoryLevel: Byte,
        listNonHierarchicalLevels: List<Byte>,
        fullUsername: String,
        traversal: GraphTraversalSource,
    ): String {
        val vertex = traversal.addV().next()
        vertex.apply {
            val dateOfDownload = Time().currentTimeToLong()

            listOntologyTags.forEach { tag ->
                property(ONTOLOGICAL_TAGS.list, tag)
            }

            property(MANDATE_LABEL.single, mandatoryLevel)
            property(NODE_CREATED.single, dateOfDownload)

            listNonHierarchicalLevels.forEach { level ->
                property(NON_HIERARCHICAL_PRIVACY_CATEGORIES.list, level)
            }

            propertiesHistory.forEach { propertyHistory ->
                val propertyName = GremlinPropertyName(name = propertyHistory.key)
                property(propertyName.single, propertyHistory.actualValue.value)
            }

            propertiesHistory.forEach { propertyHistory ->
                val propertyName = GremlinPropertyName(name = propertyHistory.key)
                propertyHistory.values.forEach { valueHistory ->
                    property(
                        propertyName.list, valueHistory.value,
                        LABEL_HISTORY_PROPERTY_LOAD_DATE.single, dateOfDownload,
                        LABEL_HISTORY_PROPERTY_COLLECTION_DATE.single, valueHistory.collectionDate,
                        LABEL_HISTORY_PROPERTY_DATE_OF_DOCUMENT_CREATION.single, valueHistory.documentCreationDate,
                        LABEL_USER_CHANGE_PROPERTY_NAME.single, fullUsername
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        return vertex.id().toString()
    }
```

Errors:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]

Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Could not successfully complete backend operation due to repeated temporary exceptions after PT1M40S


2024-03-25 10:00:52.171 [] [] [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-10] INFO  o.j.d.util.BackendOperation - Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
    at io.vavr.API$Match.of(API.java:5092)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.lambda$static$0(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.mutateMany(CQLStoreManager.java:304)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:84)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:99)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:147)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.mutate(CacheTransaction.java:91)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.KCVSCache.mutateEntries(KCVSCache.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.mutateEdges(BackendTransaction.java:210)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommitAddRelationMutations(StandardJanusGraph.java:788)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommit(StandardJanusGraph.java:650)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:899)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1524)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:158)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.access$txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:12)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG$txTransactionSuspend$1.invokeSuspend(TransactionJG.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:291)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.fromErrors(AllNodesFailedException.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:326)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:219)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]

    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:237)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.execAsyncUnlogged(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$0(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:51)
    at io.vavr.Value.forEach(Value.java:340)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$1(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$mutate$2(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutate(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:61)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:318)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
2024-03-25 10:00:52.392 [] [] [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-10] INFO  o.j.d.util.BackendOperation - Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
    at io.vavr.API$Match.of(API.java:5092)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.lambda$static$0(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.mutateMany(CQLStoreManager.java:304)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:84)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:99)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:147)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.mutate(CacheTransaction.java:91)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.KCVSCache.mutateEntries(KCVSCache.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.mutateEdges(BackendTransaction.java:210)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommitAddRelationMutations(StandardJanusGraph.java:788)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommit(StandardJanusGraph.java:650)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:899)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1524)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:158)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.access$txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:12)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG$txTransactionSuspend$1.invokeSuspend(TransactionJG.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:291)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.fromErrors(AllNodesFailedException.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:326)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:219)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:237)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.execAsyncUnlogged(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$0(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:51)
    at io.vavr.Value.forEach(Value.java:340)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$1(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$mutate$2(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutate(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:61)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:318)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
2024-03-25 10:00:52.640 [] [] [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-10] INFO  o.j.d.util.BackendOperation - Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
    at io.vavr.API$Match.of(API.java:5092)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.lambda$static$0(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.mutateMany(CQLStoreManager.java:304)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:84)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:99)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:147)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.mutate(CacheTransaction.java:91)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.KCVSCache.mutateEntries(KCVSCache.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.mutateEdges(BackendTransaction.java:210)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommitAddRelationMutations(StandardJanusGraph.java:788)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommit(StandardJanusGraph.java:650)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:899)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1524)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:158)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.access$txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:12)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG$txTransactionSuspend$1.invokeSuspend(TransactionJG.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:291)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.fromErrors(AllNodesFailedException.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:326)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:219)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:237)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.execAsyncUnlogged(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$0(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:51)
    at io.vavr.Value.forEach(Value.java:340)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$1(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$mutate$2(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutate(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:61)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:318)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
2024-03-25 10:00:52.925 [] [] [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-10] INFO  o.j.d.util.BackendOperation - Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
    at io.vavr.API$Match.of(API.java:5092)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.lambda$static$0(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.mutateMany(CQLStoreManager.java:304)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:84)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:99)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:96)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:147)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.mutate(CacheTransaction.java:91)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.KCVSCache.mutateEntries(KCVSCache.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.mutateEdges(BackendTransaction.java:210)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommitAddRelationMutations(StandardJanusGraph.java:788)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommit(StandardJanusGraph.java:650)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:899)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1524)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:158)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG.access$txTransactionSuspend(TransactionJG.kt:12)
    at project.janusGraph.TransactionJG$txTransactionSuspend$1.invokeSuspend(TransactionJG.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:291)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: All 1 node(s) tried for the query failed (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NodeUnavailableException: No connection was available to Node(endPoint=/10.10.20.11:9042, hostId=ff175b9d-8085-4edd-a41c-809551c576e9, hashCode=4bd2521e)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.fromErrors(AllNodesFailedException.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:326)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:219)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:237)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.execAsyncUnlogged(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:71)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$0(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:51)
    at io.vavr.Value.forEach(Value.java:340)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$null$1(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.lambda$mutate$2(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutate(CQLSimpleMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.function.mutate.AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.mutateMany(AbstractCQLMutateManyUnloggedFunction.java:61)
```

Comment: It is not clear from the code how large the commit sizes are. Since your vertices are very big I would try to limit commit sizes to just 10 vertices or so.

Comment: @HadoopMarc Thank you. And how to do it and where?

Comment: traversal.tx().commit()  You can add a counter to your loop and commit every 10 vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything seems to have worked! Is it true that now the large number of transactions for each commit is very bad?

Comment: One commit is one transaction. There is a balance: too small transactions incur a lot of overhead, in particular for batch loading. A too large transaction runs out of (memory) resources and may lock nodes for longer a time than necessary.